# StreamWriter не до конца записывает данные в файл

Tags: c#, json, .net, файлы

У меня есть следующий код

```
string urlAddress = $"https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list";

WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new(stream);
string s = sr.ReadToEnd();

Dictionary<string, string> symbolId = new();

string[] symbol = Regex.Matches(s, "(?<=\"symbol\":\")[^\"]+").Select(x => x.Value.ToUpper()).ToArray();
string[] id = Regex.Matches(s, "(?<=\"id\":\")[^\"]+").Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < symbol.Length; i++)
    if (!symbolId.ContainsKey(symbol[i]))
        symbolId.Add(symbol[i], id[i]);

StreamWriter sw = new(@"C:\Users\hem12\source\repos\PNL_Now\symbol_id.json");
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
sw.Write(JsonSerializer.Serialize(symbolId, options));
```

В данном коде я получаю достаточно большой список (10251 строчек в JSON). Словарь содержит правильное количество объектов, но вот при записи в файл все останавливается на 10094 строчке, при чем строчка не дописывается до конца. JsonSerializer.Serialize() работает корректно, вся проблема лишь в StreamWriter, который не может полностью записать данные в файл.
С чем это связано и как это решить?

Comment: Могу предоставить полный код если нужно

Comment: А зачем вам тут вообще `Stream`, не уж то 10к строчек, это прям зависоны при сериализации десериализации?

Comment: А что тогда вместо Stream можно использовать? Зависонов то при сериализации десериализации нет. Тем более, оказывается, что данный глюк возникает при любом количестве объектов с словаре

Comment: Да просто `File.WriteAllText("file", JsonSerializer.Serialize(symbolId));` и обратно `symbolId = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);`, вот вам две строки, без стримов, с загрузкой и выгрузкой JSON данных. Ну и да, с Regex тоже ерундой страдаете, создали класс с нужными свойствами и работаете. А, ну и `WebRequest` является устаревшим классом в C#! Используйте `HttpClient`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, через `File.WriteAllText' заметил то, что постоянно выдается ошибка "файл используется другим приложением", и решил перейти на SW

Comment: Ну и ерунду сделали. Вместо того, чтоб решить проблему, вы нашли обходной костыль. Советую всеж разобраться, почему файл занят и кем. Может вы также открыли гдет `Stream` на этот файл и забыли закрыть?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, файл используют ещё несколько методов, но когда я запускал, все эти методы были неактивны

Comment: Ну раз пишет "файл занят", значит не все они "неактивны", верно? Ну а так, вот [вся реализация вашего кода](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1e3An9), не пойму правда зачем там словарь, но дело ваше. Так что подумайте, верно ли вы реализовали все у себя, или нет...

Comment: Спасибо Вам за реализацию! Уверен, потому что только этот метод и вызывал, а он от других не зависит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Помылся - закрой душ.*

---

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new(...)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: а почему мой вариант не работает?

Comment: @Miclell Хм, потому что Вы не закрыли.

Comment: по фактам, спасибо:)

Comment: @Miclell [Использование объектов, реализующих IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects).

Comment: @aepot, спасибо, стало намного понятнее